# extract part of time.h (localtime)

Tags: c, time, ctime, time.h

I want to extract **parts** from  for example **tm_sec** or **tm_min only**, as a **simple int** (not array or string) how is that and possible (if it is) if something I do not need 100% correct time as of I do it for my own interests and just want ot know the way how to do it.
Before tried with to do something with

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char buffer [80];

time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
strftime (buffer,80,"Now it's %H:%M.",timeinfo);
puts (buffer);
```

But lack of experience stopped me, and now I have no idea what to do (just a beginner in programming)And of course sorry if there was a question like this, but I`ve tried and have not found it.

*The purpose of this is not to display only the parts I want but to edit them

Comment: Don't forget that year is coded as 'year - 1900' (so you have to add 1900 to get the actual calendar year), and that month is encoded with 0 for January to 11 for December (so you need to add one to get the normal month number).  And the `mktime()` function can take a modified `struct tm` and convert it back to a `time_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply access the members of the struct:

```
printf("The tm_seconds field is %d\n", timeinfo->tm_sec);
```

In other words, if you have a pointer to a value of type `struct tm`, you can use the arrow operator (`->`)  to access any of the members. The `tm_sec` member has type `int`, like all the other members.

You could copy the value:

```
int my_seconds = timeinfo->tm_sec;
```

and then print the copy, too:

```
printf("my seconds are %d\n", my_seconds);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I would give you rep, but do not have the ability to do so :)

Comment: @undefined: in a few minutes, you will be able to accept the answer, which will also give you some rep.

Comment: Now I can give the rep, and also mark as complete, thank you very much again, you`ve saved my enthusiasm